# Program hangs on executeBatch()

Tags: java, mysql, insert

I can't find a solution to my issue. I am executing inserts to `MySQL` DB table in 5000 batches. I have set autocommit to false and I commit manually after each `executeBatch()`. For some reason, the program hangs without any error on the `executeBatch`.

```
if (i % batchSize == 0 && i != 0) {
    prodsQuery.executeBatch();
    DBConnect.DBC.con.commit();
    System.out.print("*");
}
```

The `prodsQuery` is `preparedStatement`. I used this code before on the `MS SQL` and it all worked fine, any idea what might have changed?

EDIT:

The more I read the more I am confused. I was executing the inserts in batches because I was doing too many inserts. However from what I read now, batches shouldn't be used in that way. So what is the quickest solution to insert 407 000 rows into the db table?

Comment: export as CSV and LOAD DATA IN FILE.

Comment: Hints: 1. Are you clering the batch after you're done each time? 2. Put a smaller set of statements in the batch; 3. Open a MySQL CLI and execute `show processlist` when your code is running, to see what's happening. 4. I agree with e4c4's comment: better export the data and use `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: Thank you for advises I think I will go with `LOAD DATA INFILE`, however why was I able to use that code in `MSSQL`, do you know? I found on the internet that some people were saying that it was hanging on `executeBatch` because each row was in separated transaction. But that should be prevented by setting `autocommit` to `false`, right?

Comment: What if I also need to add a custom value to one of the columns, so it is not just data from the file, any idea?